# Firebase + node JS Sync error?

Tags: javascript, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

[image: Firebase node is like pic.]

My node js code is as below

```
     for(v in sna.val()){
            console.log("each"+va);
            console.log(v);
          var fourthRef=ref.child(val+'/reservation/'+va+"/"+v);
           fourthRef.once('value').then((sn)=>{
              console.log(v);
              console.log("second val")
    });
```

The problem is...
fourthRef only search for the last da086aee-3ebf-4684-b91b-53af49fe6d84 node ignoring 599b04e8-5731-4ea1-a326-69a7bca2e937 node.

Log is as below. as you can see value before second val, only search for da086aee-3ebf-4684-b91b-53af49fe6d84 one.

```
each0CB2B77BB2BB

599b04e8-5731-4ea1-a326-69a7bca2e937

each0CB2B77BB2BB

da086aee-3ebf-4684-b91b-53af49fe6d84

da086aee-3ebf-4684-b91b-53af49fe6d84

second val

da086aee-3ebf-4684-b91b-53af49fe6d84

second val
```

Comment: try `let fourthRef` instead of `var fourthRef`

Answer (score 0):

`once()` is asynchronous, meaning it doesn't block your loop to wait for it to give back results.  The results of the query happen some time later, and are available in the `then()` callback of the promise returned immediately by `once()`.

Your loop is effectively kicking off several queries all at the same time, but not really waiting for any of them to complete.  The results from each query are coming in after loop has finished.  Whatever it is you're trying to do, you'll have to rewrite this code, or otherwise do something that correctly uses the promises returned by once().